# iphone :How to do symobolication of crash report?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app i got crash report

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)

Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000

Crashed Thread:  7

In Thread 7 :


Thread 7 Crashed:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x3728ba96 0x37278000 + 80534

1   CFNetwork                       0x36617b84 0x36616000 + 7044

2   CFNetwork                       0x36617af6 0x36616000 + 6902

3   MusicBandApp                    0x0000bbfc 0x1000 + 44028

4   MusicBandApp                    0x0000b740 0x1000 + 42816

5   Foundation                      0x33b88382 0x33b6b000 + 119682

6   Foundation                      0x33bfa5c6 0x33b6b000 + 587206

7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3579530a 0x35762000 + 209674

8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35796bb4 0x35762000 + 215988
```

but can"t show particular crash file name  & line number.

How can sybolicate this crash report.

Comment: Post the code where in you get this error.

Comment: Also try to run the app on device and check the device log and crash report on device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a file called symbolitecrash to process this file. This file can be located in */Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources*

1. Open the **Terminal**.
2. Copy **symbolitecrash** file to the default location shown when the terminal is opened.

   eg. Terminal window :-

   Last login: Wed Jun 22 15:28:21 on ttys000
   UserMM:~ user$

   Here, the default location is the directory "user".
3. Running this script with the -h option provides the minimal help:

   UserMM:~ user$ **symbolitecrash** -h

   usage:

   /usr/local/bin/symbolicatecrash [-Ah] [-o ] LOGFILE [SYMBOL_PATH ...]

   Symbolicates a crashdump LOGFILE which may be "-" to refer to stdin. By default,

   all heuristics will be employed in an attempt to symbolicate all addresses.

   Additional symbol files can be found under specified directories.

   Options:

   -A  Only symbolicate the application, not libraries

   -o  If specified, the symbolicated log will be written to OUTPUT_FILE (defaults to stdout)

   -h  Display this message

   -v  Verbose
4. Place the .crash file in the same location where **symbolitecrash** file is copied.
5. To add symbols to the crash log you need the dSYM file generated by the linker when you compiled your application for AppStore. In other words, when you build for AppStore you should keep the dSYM package in a safe place backed up by Time Machine. This is very important. **You should keep a copy of the dSYM for each version of your application ever shipped**. If you have the package, translating code offsets to function names with line numbers has never been easier:

$ symbolicatecrash MiMo_2011-06-22-143801_Anands-Ipod.crash myApp.app.dSYM > myApp_2011-06-22-143801_Anands-Ipod1.crash

myApp_2011-06-22-143801_Anands-Ipod1.crash is the new crash file generated in the same location.

Here is the result:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib           0x300c87ec objc_msgSend + 20
1   myApp                      0x00006434 -[BoardView setSelectedPiece:] (BoardView.m                              :321)
```

Comment: :i have query in step2, i have to copy  symbolitecrash file in local folder or copy symbolitecrash file path in a terminal?

Comment: @Ankit u have to set the path or you can copy it to root folder

Comment: i am going with set path...i given the path of  symbolitecrash file

Answer (score 1):

I also described how to do this step by step in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565978/how-to-interpret-a-crashlog-with-no-references-to-a-specific-class/7648558#7648558)

It worked fine for me:

[Crash Symbolized http://k.minus.com/jk4X2obwZMI7j.png](http://k.minus.com/jk4X2obwZMI7j.png)