# iOS Crash Log Assertion Failed

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, crash-reports

I submitted my app to the App Store and it was rejected by Apple saying that it crashed on launch on the iPad Mini 2 with Wifi.  Problem is I do not have an iPad Mini 2, also I tested my app on all the iPad and iPhone simulators, so I am unable to replicate this.  I'm hoping someone can help here, because I need this app for next week.  Apple sent and *.ips file crash log that contained a bunch of stuff like this which makes no sense to me...especially if I can't even replicate this so called crash:

```
{"app_name":"Appx","app_version":"1.0","bundleID":"com.lvg.apps.Appx","adam_id":0,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1 (12B411)","slice_uuid":"db078062-fe42-3ae4-aeed-ed90b7d46769","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"Appx"}
Incident Identifier: 513B0449-0AF2-4D62-BC90-CFB6EBD3A8DA
CrashReporter Key:   6a18f646ed25bac148a5a1b6d8115934197adaaa
Hardware Model:      iPad4,4
Process:             Appx [412]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7A07DF63-F228-4C67-9404-1EA7B06B1B17/Appx.app/Appx
Identifier:          com.lvg.apps.Appx
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]

Date/Time:           2015-01-08 14:30:09.564 -0800
Launch Time:         2015-01-08 14:30:08.971 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
UDID:                add99a851e7f7c61671e6c59ea1f985dc1ce4131
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010008160c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
2015-01-08 14:30:09.349 Appx[412]: <Error> assertion failed: 12B411: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [AD580443-238D-3997-8D09-004C210D0C18]: 0x7d

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Appx                    0x000000010008160c 0x100014000 + 448012
1   Appx                    0x00000001000816ec 0x100014000 + 448236
2   UIKit                           0x000000018b7de3cc 0x18b75c000 + 533452
3   UIKit                           0x000000018b9f522c 0x18b75c000 + 2724396
4   UIKit                           0x000000018b9f79ac 0x18b75c000 + 2734508
5   UIKit                           0x000000018b9f6044 0x18b75c000 + 2728004
6   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f2b163c 0x18f298000 + 103996
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f76120 0x186e98000 + 909600
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f75228 0x186e98000 + 905768
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f7384c 0x186e98000 + 899148
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186ea11f0 0x186e98000 + 37360
11  UIKit                           0x000000018b7d7788 0x18b75c000 + 505736
12  UIKit                           0x000000018b7d2780 0x18b75c000 + 485248
13  Appx                    0x0000000100083cd0 0x100014000 + 457936
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198102a04 0x198100000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198200c94 0x198200000 + 3220
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001980e897c 0x1980d8000 + 67964
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001980db3b0 0x1980d8000 + 13232

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821bc78 0x198200000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b5390 0x1982b4000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b4fa4 0x1982b4000 + 4004

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821bc78 0x198200000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b5390 0x1982b4000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b4fa4 0x1982b4000 + 4004

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821bc78 0x198200000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b5390 0x1982b4000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b4fa4 0x1982b4000 + 4004

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821bc78 0x198200000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b5390 0x1982b4000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982b4fa4 0x1982b4000 + 4004

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000014fe01180   x1: 0x000000018bf3ce25   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000017406d0c0
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000120
    x8: 0x00000001000a3000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000081a599349131  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x000000000000001f  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000015  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000197aac160  x17: 0x000000018b76e90c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001000ab000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x000000017406d0c0  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000199349130  x25: 0x000000018bf3d40c  x26: 0x000000018bf40c2a  x27: 0x00000000000000b0
   x28: 0x00000001000ab000  fp: 0x000000016fdea390   lr: 0x0000000100080f94
    sp: 0x000000016fdea310   pc: 0x000000010008160c cpsr: 0x80000000
```

Comment: I think you need to symbolicate the log.

Comment: My apologies, I'm don't know what you mean.  This is my first  app and first rejection from Apple.  Could you possible point me to what you mean or a note somewhere with instructions?

Comment: Google "symbolicate".

Comment: (I had this bookmarked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7007146/581994 -- note that it's old, so probably there's better info elsewhere.)