# App Review has rejected my app: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, crash

We testing my app with iPhone 6s/iPhone 6/iPhone 5, no bugs and crash report, but when we submit to iTunesConnect, the App Review team has rejected my app, they said this app crashed on launch.

We can not reproduce this crash, I have no idea what the crash log below means. I would be really happy if anybody could explain me what this crash log could relate to and how I could solve it. Many many thanks to all those who are willing to help others.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
2015-02-05 06:00:28.268 chuanBang[993]: <Error> assertion failed: 12B411: libxpc.dylib + 51955 [04694BEB-256F-3132-A00F-0C82B79BC689]: 0x7d
2015-02-05 06:00:29.105 chuanBang[993]: <Error>  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
2015-02-05 06:00:29.517 chuanBang[993]: <Error> CoreLocation: Could not get ideal gyro update interval, assuming 0.005000 s
2015-02-05 06:00:30.615 chuanBang[993]: <Warning> Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application
2015-02-05 06:00:30.619 chuanBang[993]: <Warning> ËØ∑Ê±ÇÂ§±Ë¥•‰∫Ü
2015-02-05 06:00:30.623 chuanBang[993]: <Warning> ËØ∑Ê±ÇÂ§±Ë¥•‰∫Ü

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x26988d62 0x342bfc72 0x26988ca8 0x2c3084 0x3499b096 0x349a0d0e 0x348c0934 0x33acdbb8 0x33ae4e30 0x33ae48b4 0x342bfdba 0x2689aa18 0x2689a78e 0x2dd4c04c 0x29e8c97c 0x1b2a1a 0x3485baaa)
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34920dfc 0x3490c000 + 85500
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x349a0d0e 0x3499d000 + 15630
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x348c0934 0x34877000 + 301364
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33acdbb8 0x33acd000 + 3000
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae4e30 0x33acd000 + 97840
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae4ee6 0x33acd000 + 98022
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae4b9c 0x33acd000 + 97180
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae4e44 0x33acd000 + 97860
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae48b4 0x33acd000 + 96436
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x342bfdba 0x342b9000 + 28090
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2689aa18 0x26881000 + 104984
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2689a78e 0x26881000 + 104334
12  GraphicsServices                0x2dd4c04c 0x2dd43000 + 36940
13  UIKit                           0x29e8c97c 0x29e1e000 + 452988
14  chuanBang                       0x001b2a1a 0xad000 + 1071642
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3485baac 0x3485a000 + 6828
```

Comment: If u integrated BugSense or crashlytics to ur application.Then check where & at which line u r getting this crash..It clearly tells at which line it crashed..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007146/iphone-how-to-do-symobolication-of-crash-report

Answer (score 0):

The crash log itself is not useful. I suggest integrating a crash reporting SDK into your app and when a crash does happen, it will give you a lot more info than you're currently getting.

Some crash reporters to look over:

[Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com)

[HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net)

Once you have one of these integrated into your app, submit the app again to Apple (If you cannot reproduce the error) and if it crashes their side, you'll have a much better idea where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I think whenever you are testing your app at that time you always allow for Notification permission Popup & Location service permission popup.

Please try by click "Don't allow" when these popup are show.